# PHP MIME header

Tags: php, email, mime

I have somes problems with my php mailer, i receive only the source code not interprated.

Someone can check my headers?

```
$recipient = str_replace(Array("\r","\n"),"",$this->to);
$headers = 'From: "xxx.ch" <contact@xxx.ch> '."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path: <postmaster@xxx.ch>' . "\r\n";
if ( isset($this->replyTo) ){
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: contact@xxx.ch' . "\r\n";
}
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"".$random_hash."\""; 
$body = '--'.$random_hash."\r".' 
         Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"'."\r".'
         Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'."\r".'

         Merci d\'utiliser un client mail supportant le format HTML'."\r".'

        --'.$random_hash."\r".'

        Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"'."\r".'
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'."\r";
$body .= $this->HTMLBody ."\r".'--'.$random_hash.'--';
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your server setup to send email? What SMTP service is running? Is PHP configured properly to send email?

Comment: Yes server config is ok, but for some old mail client don't support html so i must to add support for them and now with MIME i have a lot of bugs :-(

Comment: Have you looked at using PEAR's MIME mail package instead of doing it by hand?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i can't install new package on my server...

Comment: Then, don't use PEAR.  Use PHPMailer or similar.  Either way, coding MIME headers by hand, and especially in a hackish way, is not worth your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would agree with other commenters that you should look into a 3rd-party library rather than doing this by hand, your current problem is probably to do with line-endings and whitespace, which MIME is very picky about.

You currently have lots of code like this:

```
$body = '--'.$random_hash."\r".' 
         Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"'."\r".'
         Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'."\r"; // (and so on)
```

You are carefully inserting a carriage return (`"\r"`) but then embedding a newline and lots of whitespace into the next single-quoted string as well.

Instead, you should **only** include the carriage return, and make sure all other whitespace is outside the single quotes (you want the PHP to be readable, but for that not to affect the output):

```
$body = '--' . $random_hash . "\r"
         . 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"'."\r"
         . 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'."\r"; // (and so on)
```